# Angular-keyboard skips elements in ng-repeat when selecting the active element

Tags: angularjs, keyboard

How do I make [angular-keyboard](https://github.com/bfanger/angular-keyboard) select the first element in a list that contains some elements produced by `ng-repeat` and some elements that are hard-coded? Whenever I have a `kb-item` outside of the `ng-repeat`, it will only apply `.kb-active` to the first of the hard-coded items.

For example, this markup results in the `kb-active` class being applied to "Static 1":

```
<ul kb-list>
  <li kb-item="item" ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items">{{item}}</li>
  <li kb-item>Static 1</li>
  <li kb-item>Static 2</li>
</ul>
```

Here is a jsfiddle that further illustrates this example: http://jsfiddle.net/9epc2ttf/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the item you want to be set as active in ng-model

```
<ul kb-list ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyControler as ctrl"
ng-model="ctrl.selected">
```

And in your controller assign the item to selected.

```
app.controller('MyControler', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   this.items = ['Repeat 1','Repeat 2','Repeat 3'];
    this.selected = this.items[0];
}]);
```

Based on the documentation here:
https://github.com/bfanger/angular-keyboard#kbselect

Solution in JSfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/9epc2ttf/2/